# Why can't I enable unicode Edit control in Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I set `Character set` to `Use Unicode Character Set` but when show window, its title still have square character. How can I fix it? Thank!

[image]

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wClass;
    ZeroMemory(&wClass, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wClass.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hIcon = NULL;
    wClass.hIconSm = NULL;
    wClass.hInstance = hInst;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WinProc;
    wClass.lpszClassName = L"Window Class";
    wClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    RegisterClassEx(&wClass);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL, 
        L"Window Class", 
        L"/ce 但是，这样做并不能保证在对话框编辑器创建控件之前将加载所需的库。", 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        200, 200, 300, 0, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: This is a problem with the font. You need a font that includes glyphs for the characters you want to display.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Sorry I'm new to c++ and Win32, can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: You know that you're creating your own window class, instead of using the existing window class for Edit Controls? This matters - for your windows, you are responsible for the fonts.

Comment: It is not a font problem, he's using Windows 8 and would have noticed the Chinese glyphs not displaying properly in his text editor.  It is probably caused by the compiler not using the correct encoding to read the source code file.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes I use Windows 8, I dont think the problem is complier (I use Visual Studio 2013), because when I create a Edit control inside the window, then when run it I copy Unicode text to it, it still same problem.

Comment: @MSalters: When I use default windows class, the problem still not resolved (use Unicode Character set).

Comment: @HansPassant: Different windows can use different fonts. His text editor probably uses a font which does include CJK glyphs, but that does not mean every window does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer, just because I can't put images in a comment ...

I just did exactly what you did, same code, Windows 8.1 x64 VS2012 UK English, and here's the result I get:

[image: result]

Unless you ignored the prompt to save your source file as a UNICODE file, you should have got the same result - I don't see that there are any other differences unless you have some strange settings in your Region/Language section of Control Panel.

If you still get the problem, you'll have to double-check all of your settings and maybe post more code and/or a dump of your compiler command line.

Comment: I use Windows 8.1 x86 VS 2013 US English. I accepted the prompt, too. Even if I add a Edit control (Wide character) then when run I copy these text to it, it still show emty squares. I dont change any settings of VS, both global preferences/settings and solution/project setting, except Unicode chaset.